# Simple Search Engine Only Works With One SQL Row

Tags: php, arrays, search, mysqli

I'm making a rather simple search engine with PHP and I've ran into a problem... The engine will only work for one SQL row. In the table the PHP is connected to, there are two rows. One named "The Painful Truth" and the other "Darkness Rising". If you type "darkness" or "rising" into the search bar it will come back with "Darkness Rising" as expected. However, if you input "the", "painful", or "truth" into the bar it will come back with zero results.(P.S. "The Painful Truth" is the first entry in the table) I attempted to debug it by listing out the song names in the table, the search, and the array after exploding the song names. They all line up like they *should* work, but alas, they don't. 

The code below takes the input and removes characters and spaces

```
$lower = strtolower($_POST["text"]); 
$characterRemover = preg_replace('/[^ \w]+/', '', $lower);
$search = str_replace(' ' , '' , $characterRemover); 
echo "<strong>". $search . "</strong><br>";
```

The code below takes data from the database, explodes the string and tries to find a match.

```
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
       $Slower = strtolower($row["song_name"]); 
       echo "Song Name: " . $Slower . "<br>";
       $song_name = explode(" " , $Slower); 

       // list array 
       $arrlength = count($song_name);

       for($x = 0; $x < $arrlength; $x++) {
           echo $song_name[$x];
           echo "<br>";
       }

       if (in_array($search, $song_name) !== false) { 
           $song_result = $row["song_name"];
       } else { 
           $song_result = "0 results buddy";
       }
   }
```

**here's how it looks when I search for "the":** 

[image: boo-hoo it didn't work]

Comment: You want to explode the string first and then build a query to ask the database for any matches - not fetch all records and iterate over them trying to find matches in PHP

Comment: @JimL I'm confused... I did explode the string first before asking for matches, didn't I? Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Just a small misunderstanding. I mean you should explode the search query (from the user) and use the search terms in a db query to only fetch the rows that match the search.

Comment: @JimL Oh, ok. But I would do it using the WHERE argument right? How can I make it find rows _containing_ what the user searched for? Because what the user searched for won't be exactly the same as the song name

Comment: have you tried to set `$search` manually! e.g. : `$search = 'the'`

Comment: show us your query

Comment: @SammySwanson something like `$stmt->prepare('SELECT * FROM table WHERE title LIKE ? AND title like ?'); $stmt->execute(array('%value1%', '%value2%'));`. You just need to loop over the exploded search term array and for each term add where clauses to the sql query and values to the array being sent to the execute method.

Comment: @JimL that could work! Will try it when I can

Comment: @JimL it works! Thank you! if you turn it into an answer i'll mark it as right

Answer (score 1):

What's happening here is that the loop is running for every single row and the variable `$song_result` is being overwritten. Try to use a flag `$found` to get the song.

```
$found = false;

while(!$found && ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())) {
    $Slower = strtolower($row["song_name"]);
    echo "Song Name: " . $Slower . "<br>";
    $song_name = explode(" " , $Slower);

    // list array
    $arrlength = count($song_name);

    for($x = 0; $x < $arrlength; $x++) {
        echo $song_name[$x];
        echo "<br>";
    }

    if (in_array($search, $song_name) !== false) {
        $song_result = $row["song_name"];
        $found = true;
    } else {
        $song_result = "0 results buddy";
    }
}
```

If you want to capture every song, then use an array or concatenate a string:

```
$songs = [];

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $Slower = strtolower($row["song_name"]);
    echo "Song Name: " . $Slower . "<br>";
    $song_name = explode(" " , $Slower);

    // list array
    $arrlength = count($song_name);

    for($x = 0; $x < $arrlength; $x++) {
        echo $song_name[$x];
        echo "<br>";
    }

    if (in_array($search, $song_name) !== false) {
        $songs[] = $row["song_name"];
    }
}

if (count($songs)) {
    $song_result = implode('<br>', $songs);
} else {
    $song_result = "0 results buddy";
}
```

**Note:** You should follow JimL's suggestion and request the info filtering the DB query via the WHERE clause. And then just show the result of the query. ;)

Comment: JimL suggestion worked, and I then set the styling and logic for the engine before you posted your answer. Although I haven't tried yours, it looks promising, and thank you for your suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
//Kindly make sure you have create a connection and select a db. this is a sample code to search from mysql db using data supplied
$msg=$_POST['search'];
if(isset($msg)){
$search=explode(' ',$msg);
$len=count($search);
$query="select * from news where ";

for($m=0;$m<$len;$m++){
$query.=" post like '%{$search[$m]}%'  || ";
}

$query.=" post like '%{$msg}%' order by upload_date desc";

if($get=mysqli_query($connect,$query)){
$contentSearch=array();
$i=0;
 while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($get)){
contentSearch[$i]=$row;
$i++;
}
echo"List of Search Items<br>";
print_r($contentSearch);
}
}
```